# Remove existing VHD on new portal azure using c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a windows application that creates a VM on the new portal of azure(not the classic VM). Somehow when I delete my currently created VM and try to recreate that VM with the same name I always get an error.

> **http://(someStorage).blob.core.windows.net/vhds/(somename)_osdisk.vhd already exists. Please provide a different blob URI as target for disk
>   '(somename)_osdisk'.**

The way that I could fix this is thru the new portal and delete the VHD with the same name of the newly created VM's VHD.

I wonder if there is a way that I could remove that VHD using C# code. Its too tiresome if I delete this always on the new portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a VHD in Azure is just a blob in Azure storage. Hence deleting a VHD is just deleting a blob in the Storage. DOT NET has a nice API for Azure Storage. See the Document [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#delete-blobs).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes this is a blob in azure storage. I don't have any problems on deleting this on the old portal. I cant seem to find a way to delete the blob on the storage account in the new portal.

Comment: You can delete a blob in the new portal: **All resources** --> **<your storage account>** --> under "Services" click **Blobs** --> **<your container>** --> choose your blob and click **Delete**

Comment: Yes but can you do this on the DOT NET API?

Comment: Yes, of cause. Read the article [Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs), and in section [Delete blobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#delete-blobs) specifically teach you how to delete a blob.

Comment: Thanks @Jack Zeng! I thought I could not use this because its not on the same namespace with the storage account.